# value of current speed freeze when the app is minimized

Tags: android, location

I am working on a simple app to get the speed of the device to use it to calculate the speed of the car.
I have a variable where I store the value of current speed and I have a problem when the app is minimized this value freeze and doesn't change and I want to change whether the is app is minimized or not,

I tried adding the below permission but it didn't work,

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

here is the code I am using to get the value of current speed:

```
  float nCurrentSpeed;

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

     num = Integer.valueOf(tv.getText().toString());

    if (location == null) {

        txt.setText("0.0");
    } else {
        nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed() * 3.6f;
        txt.setText(String.format("%.2f", nCurrentSpeed) + "");
    }
```

}

Comment: Update the value onResume... LifeCycle goes onpause idle mode